# how to lock a table for writing

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to lock a table for writing during a period of time, while leaving it available for reading.
Is that possible ?
Ideally I would like to lock the table with a predicate (for example prevent writing rows "`where country = france`").

Comment: "with a predicate" would only lock the _rows_ not the whole table. But why do you think you need that? what is the real problem you are trying to solve with that? Explicit locking is very rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to *lock* against such inserts, i.e. the query should hang and only continue when you allow it, you would have to place a `SHARE` lock on the table and keep the transaction open.

This is usually not a good idea.

If you want to *prevent* any such inserts, i.e. throw an error when such an insert is attempted, create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that throws an exception if the `NEW` row satisfies the condition.

Comment: My question about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58456874/593144 :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FOR SHARE` lock, which blocks other transactions from performing like `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, while allowing `SELECT FOR SHARE`. (Read the docs for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html [13.3.2])

For example, there are 2 processes accessing table `user_table`, in the following sequence:

1. Process A: `BEGIN;`
2. Process A: `SELECT username FROM user_table WHERE country = france FOR SHARE;`
3. Process B: `SELECT * FROM user_table FOR SHARE;`  (**In here, process B can still read all the rows of the table**)
4. Process B: `UPDATE user_table SET username = 'test' WHERE country = france;` (**In here, process B is blocked and is waiting for process A to finish its transaction**)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't prevent inserting new rows with `country = 'france' `.